# How to symbolize the following sentence

Tags: logic

I need some help with the following:

It is from the Logic book (4th Ed)

Let

```
 A:Albert jogs regularly

 H: Albert is healthy
  
 B:Bob jogs regularly
```

Given this sentence:
If Albert is healthy,he jogs regularly iff Bob does

I took the sentence up to iff as if X then Y.

I thought of several symbolizations.
Here are two of them:

*H=>(A=B)*

*(~H v A)=B*

(The answer is on the CD , but don’t want to look,
rather discuss first)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first one, reading = as biconditional.

Comment: Help with what? What are you stuck on?

Comment: It was solved. Mauro solved it